# Jinja2 block completely ignored

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, openlayers-3

this is the code for displaying some features in a map, using Flask and OpenLayer3:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-105.269487,40.016026]),
        zoom: 10
    })
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    //create empty vector
});

{% for row in geodata %}
    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([{{row['lat'],row['lon']}}], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        name: {{row['id_tweet']}}
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
{% endfor %}

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/data/icon.png'
    }))
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyle
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer)
```

This is python code:

```
@app.route('/map', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def display_geodata():
     f_obj = open(PROJECT_ROOT+'/data.csv', "rt")
return render_template('map.html', geodata = read_data_from_csv(f_obj))

def read_data_from_csv(file):
     return csv.DictReader(file)
```

Why the **for** block doesn't display anything?
While debugging, the *geodata* I can see that is not empty, and contain all the datta of the data.csv file!
Where I am wrong?

Comment: `return dict_reader = csv.DictReader(file)` should generate a syntax error, is that the actual line, or is it `return csv.DictReader(file)`?

Comment: in general, to see that this even loops properly, use console.log(row) in the loop and check the browser dev console for an output. Then you can tell if it's jinja2 or your javascript.

Comment: does it matter that you are redefining the same variable within the for loop?

Comment: @SimonFraser yeah, sorry, I corrected that.

Comment: When you view the source of the web page, do you see all the instances of for iconFeature = ..?

Comment: @KenKinder I don't know why, but some hours ago, I was able to see them, but maybe I touch something in the code or whatever, so now I don't see any of that js code.

Comment: @GG_Python nope, can't see anything in the console log

Comment: Sounds like the file is probably empty or something. I could believe the JavaScript is buggy (it looks pretty fragile), but if it's not showing up at all, my guess is that your data structure is empty. You could test this just by dumping the variable and seeing it directly {{ geodata }}

Comment: You also might try using a debugger.

Comment: @KenKinder {{geodata}} output:  &lt;csv.DictReader object at 0x000000592BAB0CC0&gt; how can I check about row content during debugging?

Comment: If you convert it to a list, it'll dump the contents. {{ list(geodata) }}. But for debugging, check out http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/debug/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to find the error, as a temporary solution I build a list of tuples instead using DictReader, now it works